# add custom clickable buttons

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an app for win phone 7. In that I need to add clickable buttons(not specific number) into a grid dynamically.and navigate the page with some information to other page.

can  any body help me please....

1. private void buildThumbs(Grid gridThumb, int p)    {

   ```
      int n;

      if (p % 3 == 0)
          n = p / 3;
      else
          n = (p / 3) + 1;

      GridLength height = new GridLength(100);


      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {

          RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();
          rowDef.MinHeight = 100;
          gridThumb.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);

      }

      MovieThumb[,] thumb = new MovieThumb[n, 3];


      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          {
              Image ni=new Image();
              ImageSourceConverter ims = new ImageSourceConverter();

              ni.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty ,ims.ConvertFromString( "/Images/book1.png"));                  

              thumb[i, j].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
              thumb[i,j].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty,i);
              thumb.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(thumb_click("sandy"));
              thumb[i, j].CoverImage = ni;
              thumb[i, j].Loading = "Loading";
              thumb[i, j].progress = false;
              gridThumb.Children.Add(thumb);
          }
      }
   ```

   }

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you trying to do or what you are asking but you might want to try the WrapPanel (from the Silverlight Toolkit [link](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291) rather than a grid - it is much easier to add items dynamically to that.

Comment: It may be easier to add items dynamically to a wrappanel as to a grid, but it's also less performant. It's ok for a few items but when you have a bigger amount of objects you want to add, you should do the extra-work and use a grid instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand your problem, but if you want to set the Column and Row number for your dynamically created buttons, you may do so with `Grid.SetColumn(buttonname, column); Grid.SetRow(buttonname, row);` before you add the object to the gridThumb.

We need some more information for what exactly you want to accomplish and what doesn't work for you to help :)

Comment: I figured it out...thank u... actually i am adding some button in grid and number of buttons are not specific they are added according to the json query parsed. and send some info to add page that at the time of navigation and each button send different info.